# Django next redirect common function?

Tags: django, django-views

In Django my landing page is `http://127.0.0.1/` But when user request any other url like `http://127.0.0.1/auth/login/?next=/project/instances/` after login he will land in the page as requested.
The problem here is when the user request for `/` i send the username from that respective view. If he asks for any other url the context is lost since that view will not be called.My question is in django is there a common function that is called after login.If so what is it ?

What ever the redirects may be a function or decorator should be called from where it is suppose to redirect to the view

Comment: could you try and frame your question a little better? Its unclear what exactly you want to accomplish.